# Axiom in Steven Lay's Book on Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

In Steven Lay's book "Analysis with an introduction to proof", in the chapter on Real Numbers, Section 2 Ordered Fields, (on p. 120 in the 5th edition of the book) the axioms for the "operation" $+$ ${\mathbb R}$ are listed, and the first one is

$A_1$:  For all $x,y\in {\mathbb R}$, $x+y\in {\mathbb R}$, and if $x=w$ and $y=z$, then $x+y=w+z$

It seems to me that, if we start by assuming that by "operation" on a set $X$ we mean a function $X\times X\rightarrow X$, there is no need for this axiom because it just says that if $p=q$ than $f(p)=f(q)$. On the other hand, if something else is meant by "operation" then it should be addressed. So my question is, is there something I am missing here that requires the statement of that axiom?

Comment: I guess he is explicitly making $+$ an operation/function as an axiom without using those words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is since you are defining R, you have to ignore your current knowledge and hence this is required.

You are essentially saying that I will have the + operation on my structure (R) and it will behave in this manner.